# Creating a ggplot boxplot with jitter duplicates my data (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I want to create a boxplot that shows individual data points as well.
This is the code that I am using:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=treatment, y=aggregate_count, color = treatment)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(position = "jitter") +
  ylab("Aggregate Count") +
  xlab("") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Using both the geom_boxplot() and geom_point() function together like this however duplicates my dataset. I noticed this because there is only one value in my dataset with a value above 30, but in the plot, I can see two. If I remove either geom_boxplot() or geom_point() the data gets displayed correctly.

Does someone have an idea on how to fix this?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: I suspect this is due to outliers being shown in the call to `geom_boxplot` as well as `geom_point`. Try setting the `geom_boxplot` arguments to exclude outliers is a possible approach eg `outlier.size = 0`. I've not tried this. Perhaps if you include data this could be confirmed.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [R ggplot geom_jitter duplicates outlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37498351/r-ggplot-geom-jitter-duplicates-outlier) and [How to exclude outliers when using geom_boxplot() + geom_jitter() in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61335789/how-to-exclude-outliers-when-using-geom-boxplot-geom-jitter-in-r)

Comment: You are right about this, thank you for the very helpful comment!
The solution:
geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = "white")

Setting the color for boxplot outliers to white makes them disappear in the white background. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Perhaps geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = NA) would be a better solution that setting the color to "white"